# MQA.withModule('shapes', function() does not work

Tags: javascript, mapquest

My Code (mapQuestHelper.js)

```
function initializeMapQuest(key, holderDiv, centerX, centerY) {
L.mapquest.key = key;
var map = L.mapquest.map(holderDiv,
{ center : [ centerX, centerY ],
layers : L.mapquest.tileLayer('map'),
zoom : 6 });

MQA.withModule('shapes', function() {
var line = new MQA.LineOverlay();
line.shapePoints = [ 39.633041, -105.318492, 39.847136, -104.674787 ];
map.addShape(line);
});

return map ;
}
```

The ERROR

```
mqa.toolkit.js?key=7&center=18.582883,73.689473:43
Uncaught TypeError: map.addShape is not a function at mapQuestHelper.js:14 at Au
(mqa.toolkit.js?key=7&center=18.582883,73.689473:43) at mqa.toolkit.js?key=7&center=18.582883,73.689473:43
at Object.At [as _moduleLoaded] (mqa.toolkit.js?key=7&center=18.582883,73.689473:43)
at mqa.module.shapes.js?1523335650918,1:1 at Au (mqa.toolkit.js?key=7&center=18.582883,73.689473:43)
at mqa.toolkit.js?key=7&center=18.582883,73.689473:43
at Object.At [as _moduleLoaded] (mqa.toolkit.js?key=7&center=18.582883,73.689473:43)
at mqa.module.graphics.js?1523335651508,2:72 at Au (mqa.toolkit.js?key=7&center=18.582883,73.689473:43)
```

Comment: Am I missing a layer ?

Comment: There is a mix of MapQuest.js (L.mapquest.key) and the MapQuest JavaScript v7 sdk (withModule). These are two different sdks. The MapQuest JavaScript v7 sdk will be sunset in June, 2018. To add a line to the MapQuest.js map, see the Miscellaneous > Adding Markers, Circles, and Polygons sample in the MapQuest.js examples.